# Am I using select2 incorrectly? Receiving JQuery reference error

Tags: jquery-select2

I just started using select2, and I added to my header the following:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

and in the debug console I receive the following error:
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery

I have included these lines after my jQuery reference.

Screenshot of the console: [image: Screenshot]

It seems to be working otherwise.  I get the reference error in both chrome and safari.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, as I suspected, it was my own fault.  A bit complicated to explain, but as it turns out I was somehow loading it twice in a modal pop-up via PHP.  No issue with select2.